# In "Return of the Jedi", why didn't Luke pilot the Imperial ship?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

I see that Luke was a competent pilot in Episode V so why was Han Solo piloting the Tydirium?

So far, I have a few hypothetical reasons:

1. Luke may not have been a competent pilot at that time.
2. Solo was a smuggler. Logically, if anyone on that ship could evade the Imperial military, it would be him.
3. Solo just wanted to be the pilot
4. Luke did not have much, if any, desire to touch the controls.

Comment: You know who else was a competent pilot? Han Solo. Why *shouldn't* Han pilot it?

Comment: You and your SO decide to go out for a drive somewhere. You both know how to drive and you're both decent drivers, and you share ownership of the car. How do you pick who drives? More importantly, who cares?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Off the top of my head, there's a few (obvious) reasons.

- Han and Chewie are the more experienced pilot/co-pilot group on the ship. Luke's not idle though, he's operating as the ship's Navigator.

> *Han entered the cockpit of the Imperial shuttle as Luke was doing some
>   fine-tuning on a rear navigator panel.* - <sub><sup>[RotJ: Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi_(novel))</sup></sub>

- Han is experienced with evading and working around Imperial ships and would have some familiarity with Imperial flight policies. Luke, by comparison is a glorified fighter-jock with extremely limited cargo ship experience.
- Han wasn't expecting Luke to be in the strike team. He wouldn't have counted on there being a second qualified pilot on board.

> *It’s Luke Skywalker, bounding through a doorway to join the briefing.
>   His friends are happy to see him back again so soon, and all the
>   rebels are glad to see the hero of the Battle of Yavin return for such
>   an important mission.* <sub><sup>[RotJ: Beware the Power of the Dark Side](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!)</sup></sub>

Comment: When you are with the guy who did the Kessel Run in less than 14 parsecs, you take a back seat and watch him piloting...

Comment: Han knows that Imperials fly casual to keep their distance without looking like they're keeping their distance.

Comment: @Taladris It was 12 parsecs! ;)

Comment: Any proof he was in the Navy?

Comment: @moonman239 - Bloody good point. He's only a Lieutenant in [Legends properties](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73940/what-type-of-captain-is-han-solo/73944#73944), not the main canon.